# Redirection of localhost/invoices

Tags: redirect, localhost, hosts

Is it possible to redirect my `localhost/invoices` directory to just `invoices` ? Perhaps by editing my hosts file?

Thanks

Comment: Your `/etc/hosts` file has nothing to do with directories. Are you talking about a web server? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that 'localhost' is currently set in the `/etc/hosts` file to your local IP address. Something like

```
 127.0.0.1 localhost
```

In which case, add invoices to this file

```
 127.0.0.1 localhost invoices
```

You will also need to modify the VirtualHost in the Apache config file (assuming you're using Apache) for that particular site:

```
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
   ServerName invoices
   DocumentRoot /path/to/new/directory
   ...
 </VirtualHost>
```

using the IP address of your server and the port you connect on. You will then need to reboot your web server.

The specifics will depend on your existing set up but hopefully this is enough to work with.